# What Javascript standard does node REPL follow?

Tags: javascript, node.js

According to [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) the following javascript is valid:

```
const o = {foo: 1, bar: 'baz'}
console.log(Object.values(o));
```

and indeed if I run this code in the Firefox developer tools console, I get the expected output:

```
Array [ 1, "baz" ]
```

But in the [REPL of node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html), I am told that `Object.values` is not a function.
Although other Object constructor methods *are* present, such as `is()` and `freeze()`.

Why is this, and how can I know beforehand what the node REPL supports and what it doesn't?

Comment: Must be an old version of node you're using

Comment: it's literally running whatever node.js you have installed.

Comment: What is `node -v`

Comment: Also, these are `Object` _static_ methods, not _constructor_ methods, whatever that means.

Comment: `node -v` gives `v6.13.1`

Comment: `Object.values()` is ES6. Node v6 only has partial support via `-harmony` flags

Comment: If you see my comment below and look at the table, you will see that in Node v6.13.1 you need to pass a command-line flag to enable that feature.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I was just following what MDN call them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `node --version` before running repl, or check `process.versions` while in repl.
Once the version is known, you can checkout http://node.green and you will know exactly what to expect.

We can guess you're running Node < 7.x, you may want to upgrade to latest LTS.

Comment: Thanks, this was really useful. Not sure why the downvotes. Helped *me* at least!

Answer (score 2):

This is entirely dependent on the Node version you have installed. See https://node.green/ for feature compatibility.

https://node.green/#ES2017-features-Object-static-methods-Object-values Answers your specific concern.